# when i generated the signed apk file and trying to run on other devices some fuction not working. can anyone have solution?

Tags: android

I am trying to run my android application on other devices, it installed properly but some XML file not working properly. It works as I expected when I installed through USB debugging. I am trying to find solution for many days. I don't get anything related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This must be the result of [Obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Add this lines in your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
          ...
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
          ...
        }
    }
```

or you can add your files in pro-gaurd